# Problems configuring https for Active Mq broker created in spring

Tags: spring, ssl, activemq-classic

**Edit**

From some experimentation I have noticed if I change my connector to:

`<amq:transportConnector name="ssl" uri="ssl://localhost:61617"/>`

Everything works fine, so I believe the problem is related to me needing some sort of additional configuration when using an https connector.  Unfortunately the information available consists of http://activemq.apache.org/http-and-https-transports-reference.html and http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/How%20to%20configure%20SSL.  Perhaps I am missing an additional step?

I have followed these instructions: http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-ssl.html

I have created a certificate as follows:

```
sudo keytool -keystore broker.ks -alias jetty -genkey -keyalg RSA
```

I have then put the broker.ks file on the classpath of my project in eclipse.  I then have the following spring configuration:

```
<beans 
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">


<amq:broker useJmx="false" persistent="false">
    <amq:persistenceAdapter>
            <amq:kahaDB />  
    </amq:persistenceAdapter>

    <!-- Configure ssl -->
    <amq:sslContext>
      <amq:sslContext keyStore="broker.ks" keyStorePassword="password"/>
    </amq:sslContext>

    <!-- Only allow connection through http -->
    <amq:transportConnectors>
            <amq:transportConnector name="https" uri="https://localhost:443"/>
    </amq:transportConnectors>

</amq:broker>
```

My keystore is definately on the classpath and the password is definately 'password' for both my password and key.  However on running the application I am prompted with:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.ssl.password
```

I then enter 'password', then I am prompted with:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.ssl.keypassword
```

I enter 'password' again an receive:

```
WARN : org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - FAILED SslSocketConnector@localhost:443: java.net.BindException: Permission denied
WARN : org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@225f1ae9: java.net.BindException: Permission denied
ERROR: org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService - Failed to start ActiveMQ JMS Message Broker. Reason: java.net.BindException: Permission denied
java.net.BindException: Permission denied
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:328)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:194)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket.<init>(SSLServerSocket.java:106)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.<init>(SSLServerSocketImpl.java:108)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl.createServerSocket(SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl.java:72)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector.newServerSocket(SslSocketConnector.java:378)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector.open(SocketConnector.java:75)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:358)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector.doStart(SocketConnector.java:146)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:253)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.http.HttpTransportServer.doStart(HttpTransportServer.java:119)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.https.HttpsTransportServer.doStart(HttpsTransportServer.java:66)
at org.apache.activemq.util.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:53)
at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector.start(TransportConnector.java:246)
at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.startTransportConnector(BrokerService.java:2162)
at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.startAllConnectors(BrokerService.java:2073)
at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.start(BrokerService.java:519)
at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService.afterPropertiesSet(XBeanBrokerService.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1536)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1409)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:574)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:161)
at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:51)
at com.bbconnecttxt.activeMq.Broker.main(Broker.java:7)
```

From what I am aware I shouldn't be prompted to enter password at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some operating systems require superuser (root) privileges to bind a connection to a *privileged* port (ports below 1024).

The following message basically reports that you are trying to bind to a port 443 (which is a privileged port) and you are not allowed to do this by the OS:

```
WARN : org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - FAILED SslSocketConnector@localhost:443: java.net.BindException: Permission denied
```

Try to configure the HTTPS for the ActiveMQ server to use port higher than 1024 for HTTPS, e.g. 8443. In general, it would be possible to run ActiveMQ under root user (not recommended), or use a tool like [authbind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authbind), but reconfiguring the port should be the most easy change.

Comment: This prevents the exception, but I am still prompted for passwords when I already provided them in <amq:sslContext>

Comment: From the Jetty documentation: If the passwords are not provided in the configuration, they may be provided as java properties (jetty.ssl.password and jetty.ssl.keypassword) else they will be prompted for. (http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/How%20to%20configure%20SSL) It seems that the amq:sslContext does not configure the password for the Jetty's SslSocketConnector. Try to configure them using mentioned system properties or try to figure out how to configure Jetty in more details from AMQ broker.

Comment: I can enter the console arguments or configure the system properties.  This behaviour however is not expected..?  Because of this, it ignores the keystore location I gave in sslContext aswell.

Comment: I've reviewed the ActiveMQ source codes for SslTransportFactory, HttpsTransportFactory, and HttpsTransportServer and it seems to me that the configuration in the amq:sslContext applies only to the ssl:/ transport, not to https:/ transport and you have to configure the values using javax.net.ssl.keyStore, javax.net.ssl.keyPassword, and javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword. See https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/activemq/trunk/activemq-optional/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/transport/https/HttpsTransportServer.java